# Stopping Autofs when in a mounted folder and the folder stays mounted

Tags: linux, autofs

I installed autofs and it's mounting a network drive to a folder in my local linux filesystem. I use `-fstype=cifs,rw` in the mount command in an  /etc/auto.smb.shares file.

If I cd into the mounted folder (or if I have got it open in a Windows Samba Share) and I stop autofs `systemctl stop autofs` the folder stays mounted.

I check with `systemctl status autofs` and it says the autofs process is dead. But I check with the `mount` command and `df -h` and the mounted folder is still there and indeed I can cd in and out of the folder from linux or browse in and out from the Windows Samba share.

If I manually unmount the drive then it unmounts it. Now if I restart autofs I get the expected behavior again. If I now cd out of the mounted folder and stop autofs it does not mount the folder if I try to cd in to it.

Am I just describing standard behavior of autofs or why does a folder stay mounted if I happen to have it open when I stop autofs?

Cheers,
Flex

Comment: Killing autofs removes the reason your automounts were being unmounted in the first place - for lack of use. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. If you want to make that an official answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop the `autofs` service, you're removing the reason your automounts were being unmounted in the first place - for lack of use. This is expected behaviour.

So, unless you manually unmount the filesystem, it will stay mounted.